# In Kotlin, how do I idiomatically access nullable nested map values, or return a default?

Tags: jvm, kotlin, nullable, non-nullable

Quick Kotlin best practices question, as I couldn't really work out the best way to do this from the documentation.

Assume I have the following nested map (typing specified explicitly for the purpose of this question):

```
val userWidgetCount: Map<String, Map<String, Int>> = mapOf(
        "rikbrown" to mapOf(
                "widgetTypeA" to 1,
                "widgetTypeB" to 2))
```

Can the following mode be any more succinct?

```
 fun getUserWidgetCount(username: String, widgetType: String): Int {
    return userWidgetCount[username]?.get(widgetType)?:0
}
```

In other words, I want to return the user widget count iff the user is known and they have an entry for that widget type, otherwise zero.  In particular I saw I can use `[]` syntax to access the map initially, but I couldn't see a way to do this at the second level after using `?.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an extension operator method for that.

```
// Option 1
operator fun <K, V> Map<K, V>?.get(key: K) = this?.get(key)
// Option 2
operator fun <K, K2, V> Map<K, Map<K2, V>>.get(key1: K, key2: K2): V? = get(key1)?.get(key2)
```

**Option 1:**

Define an extension that provides `get` operator for nullable map. In Kotlin's stdlib such approach appears with [`Any?.toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) extension method.

```
fun getUserWidgetCount(username: String, widgetType: String): Int {
    return userWidgetCount[username][widgetType] ?: 0
}
```

**Option 2:**

Create a special extension for map of maps. In my opinion, it is better because it shows the contract of the `map of maps` better than two `get`s in a row.

```
fun getUserWidgetCount(username: String, widgetType: String): Int {
    return userWidgetCount[username, widgetType] ?: 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, both work great.  I haven't decided which one I prefer (I'm not completely convinced option 2 actually shows the map of map contract better) but regardless, both are succinct solutions - I need to think more in terms of extension methods (and operators...) in the Kotlin world.